# Strapi uploaded files are not displaying on website

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, strapi

I have many files which are stored in upload_file collection in mongodb and they have relations with related content types. However when I open Strapi CMS UI, I cannot see the file attached on its content type.

I am using Strapi v3.4.6 — Community Edition.

In the first picture is showing the my one of upload_file collection item. Its relation is shown in red circle.

In the second picture is showing the my main content type collection item. You see that its id and upload_file rel id is matching.

But in Strapi UI, this file is not linked to model. The file exists in file system of Strapi. However it is not visible

[image: Here is showing the my one of upload_file collection item. Its relation is shown in red circle]

[image: Here is showing the my main content type collection item. You see that its id and upload_file rel id is matching]

[image: But in Strapi UI, this file is not linked to model. The file exists in file system of Strapi. However it is not visible]

I can add this file manually, but is there any quick way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to migrate the database. We solved with a basic script.

Run http://localhost:3000/migrate

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
var dbName = "YOURDBNAME";
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
var _db;
var _dbo;

var tables = {
    "table1": "TabLE1",
    "table2": "TABle2",
}

app.get('/migrate', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Started!')
  
  _dbo.collection("upload_file").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    result.forEach(function (item) {
      if (item.related.length > 0) {
        var related = item.related[0];
        var query = { '_id': related.ref };
        var newvalues = { $set: {} };
        newvalues.$set[related.field] = item._id;
        var tableName = related.kind.toLowerCase();
        _dbo.collection(tables[tableName]).updateOne(query, newvalues, function(err, res) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log(res != null ? res.ops : null);
        });
      }
    })
    // db.close();
  });
})


MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  _dbo = db.db(dbName);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})

function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
  return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}

// Run http://localhost:3000/migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

When uploading your image to strapi make sure your formData has these fields

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('files', image);    
formData.append('ref', 'contentTypeName');
formData.append('refId', dataItemId); 
formData.append('field', 'image');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My files have already uploaded. I just need to link those files with their related content types. How can I do that? Where can I add above code in Strapi?